# iOS 7 64-bit devices can't find an existing Segue on storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, 64-bit

I've developed an iPhone App that crashes ONLY when i launch it on 64-bit simulator (for iPhone 5S), i return this error:

> 2013-10-29 16:36:18.377 IlNostroComune[7630:70b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Receiver () has no segue with
>   identifier 'mostraSuggerimenti''

In 32bit structure everything works fine, the SEGUE exist on storyboard and his name is correct.

My app was rejected cause this problem, how can i solve?

MY DETAILED ERROR REPORT:

> 2013-10-29 16:36:18.377 IlNostroComune[7630:70b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Receiver () has no segue with
>   identifier 'mostraSuggerimenti''
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001021d4795 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000101db3991 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100f70345 -[UIViewController
>   shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0     3   IlNostroComune
>
>   0x000000010006f722 -[HomeViewController viewDidLoad] + 242    4   UIKit 
>   0x0000000100f6e524 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562   5
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000100f8ebcd
>   -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 44     6   UIKit                               0x0000000100f8f0dd -[UINavigationController
>   _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216  7   UIKit                               0x0000000100f8f1dd
>   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 83  8   UIKit                               0x0000000100f8ff87 -[UINavigationController
>   _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 547  9   UIKit                               0x0000000100f90a38 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
>   + 43  10  UIKit                               0x00000001010a4929 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100ede4c7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>   + 354     12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010336fe82 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151     13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001033649e9 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   363   14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010336fdb6
>   -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 162   15  UIKit                               0x0000000100f7e502 -[UIViewController
>   window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 264  16  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100ebd50d -[UIWindow
>   _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:]
>   + 4360    17  UIKit                               0x0000000100ebc3ff -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 36   18  UIKit                               0x0000000100ebc34f
>   -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 101    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100ebb65e -[UIWindow
>   _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 377  20  UIKit                               0x0000000100f7228a -[UIViewController
>   _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 147  21  UIKit                               0x0000000100eb6447 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   506   22  UIKit                               0x0000000100eb6595
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 275  23  UIKit                               0x0000000100ebf662 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51   24  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100e7dae8 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1449     25  UIKit                               0x0000000100e81608 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660  26  UIKit                               0x0000000100e9246b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3092    27  UIKit                               0x0000000100e928de -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79     28  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000100e82cde _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 618    29 
>   GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ea4bba
>   _PurpleEventCallback + 762    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ea4681 PurpleEventCallback + 35     31  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001021567b9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 41   32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010215658e
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010217fa53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939    34  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010217eed3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     35  UIKit
>   0x0000000100e80edd -[UIApplication _run] + 609    36  UIKit
>   0x0000000100e82a63 UIApplicationMain + 1010   37  IlNostroComune
>   0x0000000100038163 main + 115     38  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000102b205fd start + 1  39  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Maybe it's an Xcode bug, but if it works in 32 bits, check for NSInteger used with ints. NSInteger is now 64 bits in a 64 bit architecture but 32 bits in a 32 bit architecture.